# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python

Не могу понять, почему выдает ошибку:

> `if t[i] >= 0 or t[i] < 1/2:
>  IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

фрагмент кода:

```
import numpy as np

def mother_wavelet(t):
    for i in range (0, np.size(t)):
        if t[i] >= 0 or t[i] < 1/2:
            mat_psi = 1
        elif t[i] >= 1/2 or t[i] <= 1:
            mat_psi = -1
        else:
            mat_psi = 0
    return mat_psi
```

Comment: * а можно поподробнее про t, которую принимает mother_wavelet()?
Скажем, type(t) и какое значение t приходит в mother_wavelet()
* range (0, np.size(t) можно сократить до range (np.size(t))

Comment: В ошибке ответ сказан - scalar variable  
Вы пытаетесь работать с ним как со списком. У вас в функцию mother_wavelet приходит строка или число.

Пользуйтесь  
>>>import pdb
>>>pdb.set_trace()  

Сможете посмотреть какие данные в переменных в нужном месте.

Comment: в mother_wavelet()подается t - область задания(t = [0, 1])

Comment: Python с вами не согласен. Код вызова mother_wavelet и инициализации ее параметра в студию.